# Is there a way to detect a player with relative coordinates to the command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using the command: `execute if entity @p[x=21 ,y=56 ,z=-132 ,distance=..4.5]` works but won't work if I use **relative coordinates**. e.g. command:`execute if entity @p[x=~ ,y=~ ,z=~ ,distance=..4.5]`
I need a way to detect the player with relative coordinates from the block executing the command. I tried using `dx=`/`dy=`/`dz=`it does seem to work partially but I can't figure out the right parameters to use in `@p[ ]` please help.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, `/execute` is the solution, but with `positioned`:

```
/execute positioned ~1 ~2 ~3 if entity @p[distance=..4.5] run …
```